# Unable to copy data from one list / excel to new list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-foundation

I have one list with data now in other site collection I've to create same list. Now I want to copy the data from old list to new list. When I'm trying to copy the data its not copying to new list. Then I export the old list in excel and then try to paste but still in new list data is not pasting.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Use export to Excel, then in the new site collection use the app/list called "Import Spreadsheet". This columns lets you upload an excel document and then let's you choose what data you wanna import from the sheet.

It does even creates the right columns types with the same name from the old list.

[Data import from Excel spreadsheet to SharePoint list](http://wiki.plexhosted.com/kb/Microsoft_SharePoint_2013:Data_import_from_Excel_spreadsheet_to_SharePoint_list)

Comment: Is it work fine for Lookup values. The scenario is I've Three lists 1) Contact List 2) WorkLocation List 3) Attendance List. In Attendance List I'm fetching data through LOOKUP from Contact List & WorkLocation List.And its working fine. Now I've created these all list in my another site. only I want to copy the data from old list to new lists but its not copying. I dont want to add columns because list is already created with required columns only I've to copy the data.

Comment: You did not mention that in the original post. The data in excel must be like "ITEM NAME;#ITEM ID" form, and then you can copy the values into the datasheet view.

Comment: People and lookup columns works the same way so: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/725530e7-13d7-4b22-a3d2-fdfa6ebdd34f/sharepoint-2010-list-data-grid-view-and-people-lookup-fields?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious